# CF - NETCFv35.wm.armv4i.cab and netcfv35.messages.en.wm.cab

Tags: c#, deployment, compact-framework

Just want to know how do you guys provide this files for the users.

My app requires both this files and im not sure how to provide them to users.

Just pointing them to rapidshare or some other download site isnt the desired anwser.

What are your suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you think that you need to deploy these files? IMHO are they a part of the .NET CF 3.5. So, if the user has the CF 3.5 installed these files are also installed.

Comment: i figured that is the currect solution. Yes installing .NET CF 3.5 requires that user downloads the file to computer (over 30Mb) connects the device and installs it. Since apps only require this two cab files i was hoping that there would be more "slick" way of providing them ...

Comment: ok, i understand. but i think that the "slick" way could cause some problems. What will happen if the user has already the CF 3.5 installed? what will happen if the installed Version is higher than yours and you overwrite things on the target device?

Comment: u have a point Noffls ! additional question ... is it even legal to host this two files and redistribute them?

Comment: I'm not sure, but IMHO has MS a Problem with things like that. If i remember right they don't even like it if somebody redistributes their Windows Service Packs; so i think redistributing single files from their packages is also not the best idea.

Answer (score 0):

First, you do not need to redistribute the mefcf35.messages.en.wm.cab file.  This simply contains the test for exceptions and if your users are seeing or needing exception messages, then you need to improve your exception handling.

For the CF, you can include the CF in your own distribution.  You can include it [inside your own CAB](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb158796.aspx) if you wish or you can distribute it separately.  The user does not need to download the redistributable package (note the name is "redistributable"), instead you can provide them with just the CAB you need.

Of course if they are getting your app from the Marketplace, you can mark the CF as a dependency framework and the Marketplace will push it down for you.